# Unable to follow a location (URL) using cURL when open_basedir is set - API callback failing

Tags: php, api, asynchronous, curl, httpresponse

**Existing method of posting values to API**
As per the API documentation, a form has to be posted to the API URL (method="POST" and action="API_URL") with some input fields and a customer token field. The API processes and then posts response to a callback.php file on my server (fixed - can't change it). The page redirects to the API URL and then comes back to callback.php. I can access the posted vals using `$_POST` in that file. That's all about the existing method and it works fine.

**Server side post to hide the customer token**
For security reasons, I am trying to post from server side this time.

**The Problem**
Callback is not happening (code inside callback.php file not executing).

After sturggling hard with cURL to post to the API and receive callback, I realized that open_basedir is set in my server due to which `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION`. I found the following code which seems to be able to accomplish the posting even if `safe_mode` is `On` or `open_basedir` is set, provided that

> we know generally where we'll be
>   redirected to

Please go through the code below and tell me what is meant here by `if we know generally where we'll be redirected to`. Is it the URL where the API will redirect to after the processing completes? Then yes I know, it has to send callback to a callback.php file on my server, but that is not happening. 
 :-

```
function curl($url, $postVars)
{
    $go = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt ($go, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($go, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);

    //follow on location problems
    if (ini_get('open_basedir') == '' && (ini_get('safe_mode')== 'Off'))
    {
        curl_setopt ($go, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, $l);
        $syn = curl_exec($go);
        if(curl_error($go))
            return false;
    }
    else
        $syn = curl_redir_exec($go, $postVars);
    curl_close($go);
    return $syn;
}

function curl_redir_exec($ch, $postVars)
{
    static $curl_loops = 0;
    static $curl_max_loops = 20;
    if ($curl_loops++>= $curl_max_loops)
    {
        $curl_loops = 0;
        return FALSE;
    }
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postVars);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    if(curl_error($ch))
        return false;
    list($header, $data) = explode("\n\r", $data, 2);
    $http_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

    $redirect_page = "[0-9]*.html";
    $base_redirect = "http://example.com/";

    if ($http_code == 301 || $http_code == 302)
    {
        $matches = array();
        $pregs = eregi($redirect_page, $data, $matches);
        $new_url = $base_redirect . $matches[0];
        if (!$new_url)
        {
            //couldn't process the url to redirect to
            $curl_loops = 0;
            return $data;
        }
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $new_url);

        return curl_redir_exec($ch, $postVars);
    }
    else
    {
        $curl_loops=0;
        return $data;
    }
}
```

On running the code, it enters into the conditon where `$http_code` is neither `301` nor `302` (it is `200` in my case). And printing the $data gives the following:-

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Wed, 01 Sep 2010 10:02:44 GMT Server: Apache/2 X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.11 Content-Length: 0 Connection: close Content-Type: text/html
```

**Help**
Help me guys..
Any code changes to this needed?
Will cURL not work in my case? (it is an asynchronous API - it triggers the callback when it's done. The original request does not receive a return value in this kind of setup.)

Thanks
Sandeepan

Comment: If anybody can help me with some method other than cURL, check my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3609157/callback-from-api-not-happening-after-posting-parameters-to-api-url-from-server-s

Answer (score 0):

You should check what the URL was cURL requested (echo $new_url;)